# I don't want to change button background on <span> hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please take a look at my jsfiddle example and please help me how to keep button background when you hover over span text. When I hover over button, button change background - button_active.gif, but problem is when I hover over span, because then background of button was changed.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y67b63vu/1/)**

```
<div class="button">
  <a href="#" title="Opširnije...">
    <span>Više</span>
        <img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/palma/img/button.gif" onmouseover="this.src='http://mile.x3.rs/mile/palma/img/button_active.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://mile.x3.rs/mile/palma/img/button.gif'">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css to set the background image.  The javascript is quite an over-elaborate way of doing it.

Your hover effect can then change the background image at the same time as the text colour.

(If you need to do it with javascript, call the javascript on the a tag, rather than on the image)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.button span {
 font-family: 'Georgia';
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 left: 40px;
 z-index: 2;
    background: url('http://mile.x3.rs/mile/palma/img/button.gif') no-repeat;
    padding: 14px 37px 30px 37px;
}
.button:hover span:hover{background: url('http://mile.x3.rs/mile/palma/img/button_active.gif') no-repeat;}
.button:hover span, 
.button:hover:before {color: #88bfaa;}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="#" title="Opširnije...">
  <span>Više</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your span is on top of your image, so it is capturing its own hover event which invalidates the image's hover event (only one element can be hovered at once).

**Option 1 (without re-working your code)**

One solution is to add `pointer-events: none` to the CSS for your `span`. This means that the pointer does not interact with the span at all. Beware: this also means the span can't be clicked on or selected!

```css
.button span {
  font-family: 'Georgia';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none; /* this causes the hover event for span not to trigger */
}
.button:hover span,
.button:hover:before {
  color: #88bfaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <a href="#" title="Opširnije...">
    <span>Više</span>
    <img src="http://mile.x3.rs/mile/palma/img/button.gif" onmouseover="this.src='http://mile.x3.rs/mile/palma/img/button_active.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://mile.x3.rs/mile/palma/img/button.gif'">
  </a>
</div>
```

**Option 2 (a cleaner solution)**

A better solution would be to set the hover event on the entire `a` tag (since this is the one you want them to click anyway!), and to do so using CSS rather than JavaScript. It would also be better in this case to use a background image instead of a `img` tag. Below is an example implementation.

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  background: url('http://mile.x3.rs/mile/palma/img/button.gif');
  /* these are the dimensions of button.gif */
  width: 103px;
  height: 51px;
}
.button span {
  font-family: 'Georgia';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.button:hover span {
  color: #88bfaa;
}
.button:hover {
  background: url('http://mile.x3.rs/mile/palma/img/button_active.gif');
}
```

```html
<!-- the HTML is much simpler! it contains content only, no decoration -->
<a href="#" title="Opširnije..." class="button">
  <span>Više</span>
</a>
```